# Handling a RecordListList from a py2neo transaction process() call

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am processing Cypher statements using

```
result = my_cypher.my_transaction.process()
```

My issue is that I don't know how to elegantly get the result. I have stumbled onto the fact that process() returns a RecordListList but I don't know what to do with it except iterate over it. This annoys me since in this part of my code, I am processing a single statement at a time and don't really need to iterate over anything. (I am still in a single transaction, however.)

Here's why I am doing now and it is burning my soul:

```
result = cypher.tx.process()
for r in result:
    for x in r:
        node_id = x['node_id']
```

but `r` and `x` will only ever have one row each. If I could just get the result directly I'd be happier:

```
node_id = result.one().one()['node_id']
```

**EDIT 1**

I used ipython to display the list of methods available on process().  One of these was pop().  Now I have this abomination:

```
 result = cypher.process()
 one_row = result.pop()
 tmp = one_row[0]['node_id']
```

Better, but still fugly.

**EDIT 2**

Apparently there's a piece of magic in RecordList that pulls the first row from said recordset. It's an attribute called `one`. Very odd that it is not a method.

```
 result = cypher.process()
 one_row = result.pop()
 node_id = one_row.one['node_id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
try:
    node_id = result[0][0]['node_id']
except IndexError:
    # result is empty
    pass
```

Comment: Well, I didn't want to guess. I don't know why that would work. The 2,0 docs don't even say what the return object's type is.

Comment: I get `TypeError: <type 'exceptions.IndexError'> is not JSON serializable` on that statement.

Comment: Well, the `RecordListList` inherits from `list`, so it is a list. The `RecordList` inside are also iterables, so the `[0][0]` works because you have a list of lists. You should catch the IndexError if the result is empty. The TypeError is unrelated, the statement doesn't serialize anything...

Comment: Ah, that explains things - I was getting the error message in some negative unit tests when the row was quite rightfully not present.  I had been using `result[0][0][0]`